# Rails, has_attached_file path with custom model attributes

Tags: ruby, paperclip

I want to customize the has_attached_file path with some model's attributes.

This is the model with the attached file:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :with_content, :polymorphic => true

  has_attached_file :picture, {
    :styles => { :mobile => ["320x200#", :png], :original => ["1280x1024>", :jpg] },
    :path => ":rails_root/public/:class/:with_content_type/:style_:basename.:extension"
  }
}
```

Note that I'm trying to use the polymorphic attribute "with_content_type".
But It doesn't work.

---

I found the solution. Pretty simple.
Add this simple code after has_attached_file:

```
 Paperclip.interpolates :with_content_type do |attachment, style|
    "#{attachment.instance.with_content_type}"
  end
```